# Finding empty directories in Python

Tags: python, rmdir

All,

What is the best way to check to see if there is data in a directory before deleting it? I am browsing through a couple pages to find some pics using wget and of course every page does not have an image on it but the directory is still created.

```
dir = 'Files\\%s' % (directory)
os.mkdir(dir)
cmd = 'wget -r -l1 -nd -np -A.jpg,.png,.gif -P %s %s' %(dir,  i[1])
os.system(cmd)
if not os.path.isdir(dir):
    os.rmdir(dir)
```

I would like to test to see if a file was dropped in the directory after it was created. If nothing is there...delete it.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Define "empty". What if there are subdirectories? Should they be checked for data? Should they also be deleted if there is no data in them?

Comment: I don't have any subdirectories in this case just a single folder that may or may not have pics in it.

Comment: Please do not use os.system to call wget. Use subprocess.Popen

Comment: In essence: `isempty = lambda path : not next(os.scandir(path), None)`

Comment: Don't use os.listdir or try, except statements. os.scandir is orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 64):

```
import os

if not os.listdir(dir):
    os.rmdir(dir)
```

[LBYL](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-lbyl) style.
for [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp), see mouad's answer.

Comment: If the directory contains thousands of files, would `os.listdir(dir)` return size be a issue? @Corey Goldberg

Answer (score 48):

I will go with [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) like so:

```
try:
    os.rmdir(dir)
except OSError as ex:
    if ex.errno == errno.ENOTEMPTY:
        print "directory not empty"
```

[os.rmdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rmdir) will not delete a directory that is not empty.

Comment: +1: Simple.  Direct.  And it delegates **all** the tricky decision-making to the OS where it belongs.

Comment: Note that this function silently drops all other errors (such as `EACCESS`), which you may want to report.  Note that fixing that naively would probably result in reporting errors for non-empty directories, which you probably want to ignore.  Not as simple as it seems :-)

Comment: How about `else: raise`?

Comment: nice but: `NameError: name 'errno' is not defined` you need `import errno`!

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
if not os.listdir(dir): 
    print "Empty"
```

or

```
if os.listdir(dir) == []:
    print "Empty"
```

Answer (score 11):

This can now be done more efficiently in [Python3.5+](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.scandir), since there is no need to build a list of the directory contents just to see if its empty:

```py
import os

def is_dir_empty(path):
    with os.scandir(path) as scan:
        return next(scan, None) is None
```

Example usage:

```py
if os.path.isdir(directory) and is_dir_empty(directory):
    os.rmdir(directory)
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you did checked if the directory exists, and whether there is content in the directory... something like:

```
if os.path.isdir(dir) and len(os.listdir(dir)) == 0:
    os.rmdir(dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the empty directories are already created, you can place this script in your outer directory and run it:

```
import os

def _visit(arg, dirname, names):
    if not names:
        print 'Remove %s' % dirname
        os.rmdir(dirname)

def run(outer_dir):
    os.path.walk(outer_dir, _visit, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    outer_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    run(outer_dir)
    os.system('pause')
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Here is the fastest and optimized way to check if the directory is empty or not.

```
empty = False
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(dir):
    if files:
        print("Not empty !") ;
    if not files:
        print("It is empty !" )
        empty = True
    break ;
```

---

> The other answers mentioned here are **not fast** because , if you want use the usual `os.listdir()` , if the directory has too many files , it will **slow** ur code and if you use the `os.rmdir( )` method to try to catch the error , then it will simply delete that folder. This might not be something which u wanna do if you just want to check for emptyness .

Comment: Using `os.scandir` is fast, with the advantage of being clearer and not needing to generate lists that aren't use.

Answer (score 0):

I have follews [Bash checking if folder has contents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20456797/2402577) answer.

Mainly it is similiar approach as @ideasman42's answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/47363995/2402577, in order to not to build the complete list, which would probably work on `Debian` as well.

> there is no need to build a list of the directory contents just to
>   see if its empty:

---

`os.walk('.')` returns the complete files under a directory and if there thousands it may be inefficient. Instead following command `find "$target" -mindepth 1 -print -quit` returns first found file and quits. If it returns an empty string, which means folder is empty.

> You can check if a directory is empty using `find`, and processing its
>   output

```py
def is_dir_empty(absolute_path):
    cmd = ["find", absolute_path, "-mindepth", "1", "-print", "-quit"]
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
    return not output

print is_dir_empty("some/path/here")
```