# Check a folder if it contains anything python3

Tags: python-3.x, directory

I need code that's able to check a folder in the same directory as the python script if it contains either folders or files
this code from [How to check to see if a folder contains files using python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675352/how-to-check-to-see-if-a-folder-contains-files-using-python-3) doesn't work

```
import os

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('.'):

    if files:

       print dirpath, 'Contains files or folders'

    if not files:

        print dirpath, 'Contains nothing'
```

The folder I'm checking is DeviceTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working**

Try this code which uses OSError and aslo os.rmdir never directory which are not empty.So we can use this exception to solve the problem

```
import os
dir_name = "DeviceTest"
try:
    os.rmdir(dir_name)
except OSError as exception_name:
    if exception_name.errno == errno.ENOTEMPTY:
        print("Directory contains files")
    else:
        print("Directory don't contain files and is empty")
```

**Simple solution**

```
import os
dir_name = "DeviceTest"
if os.listdir(dir_name) == []:
    print("Empty")
```

Comment: does this check the current directory or do I have to change the directory to check it?

Comment: goto the root and it will check if it is empty or not,if you want to check all folders in a given folder you can walk through the entire directories

Comment: could you edit your code to have it check DeviceTest in the current directory

Comment: What exactly is DeviceTest,is it a filename or sub-directory?

Comment: Its a directory in the working directory I want to check it, if it contains anything eg files or folders

Comment: NameError: name 'errno' is not defined During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred Also this is python3

Answer (score 0):

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(folder): 
        if (files) or (dirs):
            print("NOT EMPTY: " + str(path))
        if (not files) and (not dirs):
            print("EMPTY    : " + str(path))
```