# What is the fastest way to check whether a directory is empty in Python

Tags: python, directory, path, operating-system, network-programming

I work on a windows machine and want to check if a directory on a network path is empty.

The first thing that came to mind was calling `os.listdir()` and see if it has length 0.

i.e

```py
def dir_empty(dir_path):
    return len(os.listdir(dir_path)) == 0
```

Because this is a network path where I do not always have good connectivity and because a folder can potentially contain thousands of files, this is a very slow solution. Is there a better one?

Comment: I actually don't think that is a duplicate. I want to know the answer in python, not in shell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284015/how-to-check-if-folder-is-empty-with-python#49284243

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest solution I found so far:

```
def dir_empty(dir_path):
    return not any((True for _ in os.scandir(dir_path)))
```

Or, as proposed in the comments below:

```
def dir_empty(dir_path):
    return not next(os.scandir(dir_path), None)
```

On the slow network I was working on this took seconds instead of minutes (minutes for the os.listdir() version). This seems to be faster, as the any statement only evaluates the first True statement.

Comment: This iterates through every single file in dir_path. Instead try: `return not next(os.scandir(dirpath), None)`

Comment: `[True for _ in os.scandir(dir_path)]` creates a list comprehension in memory that looks like: `[True, True, True, True]` (one hit for each scandir entry) then `any` goes over the list of Trues

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehensions

Comment: ups, weird that it actually improved speed for me then. Will adjust the answer. Thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 6):

From Python 3.4 onwards you can use `pathlib.iterdir()` which will yield path objects of the directory contents:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>>
>>> def dir_empty(dir_path):
...     path = Path(dir_path)
...     has_next = next(path.iterdir(), None)
...     if has_next is None:
...             return True
...     return False
```

Answer (score 3):

`listdir` gives a list. `scandir` gives an iterator, which may be more performant.

```
def dir_empty(dir_path):
    try:
        next(os.scandir(dir_path))
        return False
    except StopIteration:
        return True
```

Comment: definitely more readable as I can guess what each line does whereas I have to know how any works in `def check_empty_by_scandir(path): \n with os.scandir(path) as it: \n  return not any(it)`

Answer (score 3):

Since the OP is asking about the fastest way, I thought using `os.scandir` and returns as soon as we found the first file should be the fastest. `os.scandir` returns an iterator. We should avoid creating a whole list just to check if it is empty.

The test directory contains about 100 thousands files:

```
from pathlib import Path    
import os

path = 'jav/av'
len(os.listdir(path))

>>> 101204
```

Then start our test:

```
def check_empty_by_scandir(path):
    with os.scandir(path) as it:
        return not any(it)
    
def check_empty_by_listdir(path):
    return not os.listdir(path)

def check_empty_by_pathlib(path):
    return not any(Path(path).iterdir())


%timeit check_empty_by_scandir(path)
>>> 179 µs ± 878 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit check_empty_by_listdir(path)
>>> 28 ms ± 185 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit check_empty_by_pathlib(path)
>>> 27.6 ms ± 140 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

As we can see, `check_empty_by_listdir` and `check_empty_by_pathlib` is about 155 times slower than `check_empty_by_scandir`. The result from os.listdir() and Path.iterdir() is identical because Path.iterdir() uses os.listdir() in the background, creating a whole list in memory.

Additionally, as people point out, reading os.stat is not an option, which returns 4096 on empty directories in linux.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows OS there is [PathIsDirectoryEmptyA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathisdirectoryemptya). We can use it to check if folder is empty or not.

```
def is_dir_empty(path:str)->bool:
    import ctypes
    shlwapi = ctypes.OleDLL('shlwapi')
    return shlwapi.PathIsDirectoryEmptyA(path.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `os.stat`:

```py
is_empty = os.stat(dir_path).st_size == 0
```

Using Python's [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path

is_empty = Path(dir_path).stat().st_size == 0
```

Comment: In Linux on an out-of-the-box ext4 filesystem, `st_size==4096` on an empty directory.