# Python - How can the script go through directories and check if there are empty or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I have an exercise to walk through all direcories in a subdirectory and check if there are empty or not.
I already tried something but this don't work:

```
import os
path = input(">>> ")

for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    if len(dirs and files) == 0:
        print(os.listdir(dirs)) == 0
        print(root)
        print(dirs)
        print(files)
        print('--------------------------------')
    else:
        print()
```

Can you help me with it?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look into this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284015/how-to-check-if-folder-is-empty-with-python

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
'''
    Check if a Directory is empty :
'''    
if len(os.listdir(path) ) == 0:
    print("Directory is empty")
else:    
    print("Directory is not empty")
```

- You have to import os

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is does not run through the other folders in the subdirectory.
How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean immediate subdirectories, or every directory right down the tree?

Either way, you could use os.walk to do this:

os.walk(directory)
will yield a tuple for each subdirectory. Ths first entry in the 3-tuple is a directory name, so

[x[0] for x in os.walk(directory)]
should give you all of the subdirectories, recursively.