# How to check whether a folder is empty or not using python?

Tags: python

## Checking Whether A Folder Is Empty Or Not.

How can i ckeck wether a folder is empty or not using python ?
I'm creating a face recognition program in opencv and i need to check wether the folder where the testing image should be is empty ot not. Any help will be appreciated!
Ty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if folder is empty with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284015/how-to-check-if-folder-is-empty-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do

```py
if len(os.listdir(’path/to/your/folder’)) == 0:
    print("empty")
```