# Append to a list only if all files exist in a folder?

Tags: python, exception

I have this folder:
`sa`

that has folders `a`,`b`,`c`. These folders have folders:

`PST` and `DBOUND`.

If for example folder `b` has empty `pst` folder and existing `dbounds`, the following code should NOT append contents from that folder at all and skip it.

code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from glob import glob

ps=[]
db=[]
for i in glob(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\sa' + '**/*/*/*', recursive=True):
    if i.endswith('PST.shp'):
        ps.append(i)
    if i.endswith('DBOUND.shp'):
        db.append(i)
```

How to make it not append from a folder, if their subfolder has either `PST` or `DBOUND` folders empty? and append only from folders that have all the needed subfolders there?

**Explanation**

To help you understand:
If all the folders `a` and `b` are ok it returns this:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\sa\a\DBOUND\DBOUND.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\sa\a\PST\PST.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\sa\b\DBOUND\DBOUND.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\sa\b\PST\PST.shp
```

If `c` has empty either `PST` or `DBOUND` folders, it should not appear at all in the list. It should skip the folder and not append it.

Comment: wrap around an if condition to check first if the pst folder is empty or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284015/how-to-check-if-folder-is-empty-with-python might help

Comment: You should rename i to fpath to make the code easier to understand. Maybe [this post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675352/how-to-check-to-see-if-a-folder-contains-files-using-python-3) could help you!

Comment: Are the file names and the directory names consistent under each top level directory ("a", "b", and "c")?

Comment: I have made a script that checks what pst folders are empty but I am searching for something that will do it as this happens in this  loop. Not just to see which are empty but to search and simply work with the needed folders.

Comment: @brandonsimpkins Yes all these folders have subfolders with same names.