# How to check whether a directory is empty or not in Shell Scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, centos

> ### I have a directory. It is empty. If i perform ls -lrt , it shows total 0

How do I specify an If condition to perform something, only if the directory is empty.

I mean to ask how to capture that 0 value.

Comment: See: [Bash checking if folder has contents](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20456666/3776858) and [Checking from shell script if a directory contains files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/91368/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus I checked those too, but I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 13):

From [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-check-if-directory-empty/). This should help you run your statements within the if else loop. I saved the DIR in the variable

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=""
DIR="/empty_dir"
# init
# look for empty dir 
if [ "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
     echo "Take action $DIR is not Empty"
else
    echo "$DIR is Empty"
fi
# rest of the logic
```

Comment: If i were to check that the directory is not empty?

Comment: See: [Negate if condition in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26475397/3776858)

Answer (score -3):

Remove the `-A` option :

```
$ mkdir /tmp/aaa
$ ls /tmp/aaa
$ a=\`ls /tmp/aaa`
$ [[ -z $a ]]
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: And if there's a hidden (ex `.file`) in the directory? It would still report as empty, yes? Is that not the reason for the `-A` option?

Comment: right. ls -A will list the hidden files like .file, but not . and ..

Comment: So, a hidden file inside the directory is ignored by your answer, proving it wrong...