# How to test for an empty directory, no matter what its size, in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

Suppose I have a directory `C:/Test` that is either empty or contains more than 2000000 files, all with the same extension (e.g. `*.txt`).

How can I use Python to determine if the directory is empty **WITHOUT** the enumeration of files?

Comment: Here is the answer that you're looking for :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215334/finding-empty-directories-in-python

Comment: This is an interesting approach (using rmdir); but, I really do not wish to remove the directory when it is empty. I just wish to know if it is or is not empty --- that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import os
if not os.listdir('C:/Test'):
    print "empty"
```

edit:
test run

```
for x in range(0, 3000000):
    open(str(x), 'a').close()

print not os.listdir('.')
```

output: False

Comment: I don't believe this will handle a directory that contains a very large number of files.

Comment: @user1435385 I'm not sure what you mean by "a very number of files."

This code will tell you if a directory is empty -- as far as I know it doesn't matter what files are in the directory.

Did you mean, "A very large number of files?" If so then you may be correct cause I haven't tried that.

Comment: @user1435385 ahhh. I replied to fast that is what you meant!

Comment: @user1435385 I just created a directory with 3,000,000 files and this code functioned properly.

Comment: This works ok for my purposes @rocktheartsm41. However, there may be a more general approach for getting information on directories in Windows (e.g. their size) when python 3.5 is released :-).

Answer (score 9):

I realise this is quite an old question but I found this as I was looking to do a similar thing and I found [os.scandir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) to be useful in combination with [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any). scandir() will return an iterator of entries in a directory rather than a list. any() can evaluate if the iterator is non-empty.

```
for _ in os.scandir(path):
 print('not empty')
 break
```

or

```
if any(os.scandir(path)):
   print('not empty')
```

Comment: Since Python 3.6 `os.scandir()` is a context manager, so now the scandir iterator requires that you call its `close()` method. "If a scandir() iterator is neither exhausted nor explicitly closed a ResourceWarning will be emitted in its destructor." See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir

Answer (score 0):

```
def isempty(dirpath):
  """ Check the given directory path to determine if it is empty. The special entries '.' and '..' are not considered.

  :param dirpath: A directory path which may be a PathLike object

  :return: True if the directory is empty, else False

  :raises FileNotFoundError: If the directory does not exist
  """
  import os

  try:
    with os.scandir(dirpath) as it:
      for inode in it:
        raise FileExistsError()
  except FileExistsError:
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

The above Python code uses scandir to efficiently check for an empty directory and will correctly close the scandir iterator in order to not cause a ResourceWarning to be emitted in the scandir destructor.